# Поиск значений в JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью `JS` или `jQuery` осуществить поиск в переменной, содержащей JSON-data следующего вида:

```
{  
    "A":"5 7 7 6 5 5",
    "A":"0 0 2 2 2 0",
    "A+":"x x 3 2 2 1",
    "A#":"x 1 3 3 3 1",
    "A#+":"x x 4 3 3 2",
    "A#5":"x 1 3 x x x",
    "A#6":"x 1 3 3 3 3",
    "C":"x 3 2 0 1 0",
    "C+":"x x 6 5 5 4",
    "C#":"x 4 6 6 6 4",
    "Gsus2addEb":"3 x 1 2 3 0",
    "Gsus4":"3 2 0 0 1 3"
}
```

Скажем, нужно найти все значения для `A`, а именно `5 7 7 6 5 5` и `0 0 2 2 2 0` и записать их в JS-массив.

В данных находятся гитарные аккорды и их т.н. транскрипция. Возможно правильнее будет привести структуру к виду, указанному ниже:

```
{"chord":"A", "chord_transcription":"0 0 2 2 2 0"}
```

Но, надеюсь, что можно обработать и в том виде, который в первом примере.
Спасибо.

Comment: Задавайте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Comment: в одном объекте не может существовать два одноименных свойства, коими являются А. Вам нужно заменить объект на массив либо же сделать как-то по-другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не может быть двух одинаковых ключей одного объекта.
Т.е. при передаче онных в строке, парсер уберёт все подобные ключи, а значением оставит последнее значение, в данном случае `"0 0 2 2 2 0"`.
Распарсенный объект будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получить же `A` можно так:

```
var input = '{      "A":"5 7 7 6 5 5",    "A":"0 0 2 2 2 0",    "A+":"x x 3 2 2 1",    "A#":"x 1 3 3 3 1",    "A#+":"x x 4 3 3 2",    "A#5":"x 1 3 x x x",    "A#6":"x 1 3 3 3 3",    "C":"x 3 2 0 1 0",    "C+":"x x 6 5 5 4",    "C#":"x 4 6 6 6 4",    "Gsus2addEb":"3 x 1 2 3 0",    "Gsus4":"3 2 0 0 1 3"}';
var A = JSON.parse(input).A; // "0 0 2 2 2 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Я новичёк в JS но подобную задачу решал с помощью простого for и прохода match 
то есть где-то так

`var search_string = "то что ищем";
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(JSON).length - 1; i++) {
  if (JSON[i].match(eval('{' + ('/' + search_string + '/gi') + '}')) != null){
    console.log(JSON[i]);
  }
}`

могу сказать что среди более чем 700 вложений на CoreDuo 3ГГц ищет почти мгновенно